# Json Dropdown list

Tags: jquery, json

When I click on the department to install the subject, the services to install when I click on the subject. But matters did not see when I click on services. I think it is inaccurate to describe the json. Can you help me with this. Thank you.
My Jquery Code;

```
/* <![CDATA[ */

(function($) {

$.fn.changeType = function(){

    var data = [
        {
        "department": "IT",
        "subject": [
                {"title":"Programmer",
                        "services" :[
                        {"name":"example1"},
                        {"name":"example2"}
                                  ]

                },
                {"title":"Solutions Architect"},
                {"title":"Database Developer"}
                ]
        },
        {"department": "Accounting",
        "subject": [
                {"title":"Accountant"},
                {"title":"Payroll Officer"},
                {"title":"Accounts Clerk"},
                {"title":"Analyst"},
                {"title":"Financial Controller"}
                ]
        },
        {
        "department": "HR",
        "subject": [
                {"title":"Recruitment Consultant"},
                {"title":"Change Management"},
                {"title":"Industrial Relations"}
                ]
        },
        {
        "department": "Marketing",
        "subject": [
                {"title":"Market Researcher"},
                {"title":"Marketing Manager"},
                {"title":"Marketing Co-ordinator"}
                ]
        }
        ]

        var options_departments = '<option>Select<\/option>';
        $.each(data, function(i,d){
            options_departments += '<option value="' + d.department + '">' + d.department + '<\/option>';
        });
        $("select#departments", this).html(options_departments);

        $("select#departments", this).change(function(){
            var index = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;
            var d = data[index-1];  // -1 because index 0 is for empty 'Select' option
            var options = '';
            if (index > 0) {
                $.each(d.subject, function(i,j){
                            options += '<option value="' + j.title + '">' + j.title + '<\/option>';
                });
            } else {
                options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
            }
            $("select#subject").html(options);
        })
};


        $("select#subject", this).change(function(){
            var index = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;
            var j = data[index-1];  // -1 because index 0 is for empty 'Select' option
            var options = '';
            if (index > 0) {
                $.each(j.services, function(i,b){
                            options += '<option value="' + b.name + '">' + b.name + '<\/option>';
                });
            } else {
                options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
            }
            $("select#services").html(options);
        })




})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#search").changeType();
});

/* ]]> */
```

My html code;

```
<form id="search" action="" name="search">
    <select name="departments" id="departments">
        <option>Select</option>
    </select>

    <select name="subject" id="subject">
        <option>Select</option>
    </select>

    <select name="services" id="services">
        <option>Select</option>
    </select>

</form>
```

Comment: So your problem is that you want to display the related services in the third select?

Comment: yes. this is my problem. third select does not work

Comment: Ok, i posted an answer where you see values in the third select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited your code and now it works (check it by selecting the first "IT" then "Programmer" in the fiddle). Of course if there are no "Services" nothing is shown in the third select.
You should add some logic to it so that it shows the third select only if there are services related to your subject

```
(function($) {


    var data = [
        {
        "department": "IT",
        "subject": [
            {
            "title": "Programmer",
            "services": [
                {
                "name": "example1"},
            {
                "name": "example2"}
                          ]

            },
        {
            "title": "Solutions Architect"},
        {
            "title": "Database Developer"}
        ]},
    {
        "department": "Accounting",
        "subject": [
            {
            "title": "Accountant"},
        {
            "title": "Payroll Officer"},
        {
            "title": "Accounts Clerk"},
        {
            "title": "Analyst"},
        {
            "title": "Financial Controller"}
        ]},
    {
        "department": "HR",
        "subject": [
            {
            "title": "Recruitment Consultant"},
        {
            "title": "Change Management"},
        {
            "title": "Industrial Relations"}
        ]},
    {
        "department": "Marketing",
        "subject": [
            {
            "title": "Market Researcher"},
        {
            "title": "Marketing Manager"},
        {
            "title": "Marketing Co-ordinator"}
        ]}
    ]
    var selectedDepartment, selectedSubject;

    $.fn.changeType = function() {

        var options_departments = '<option>Select<\/option>';
        $.each(data, function(i, d) {
            options_departments += '<option value="' + d.department + '">' + d.department + '<\/option>';
        });
        $("select#departments", this).html(options_departments);

        $("select#departments").change(function() {
            var index = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;

            var d = data[index - 1]; // -1 because index 0 is for empty 'Select' option
            selectedDepartment = d;
            var options = '';
            if (index > 0) {
                options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
                $.each(d.subject, function(i, j) {
                    options += '<option value="' + j.title + '">' + j.title + '<\/option>';
                });
            } else {
                options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
            }
            $("select#subject").html(options);
        })
    };


    $("select#subject").change(function() {
        var index = $(this).get(0).selectedIndex;
        selectedSubject = selectedDepartment.subject[index -1];
        var options = '';
        if (index > 0) {
            $.each(selectedSubject.services, function(i, b) {
                options += '<option value="' + b.name + '">' + b.name + '<\/option>';
            });
        } else {
            options += '<option>Select<\/option>';
        }
        $("select#services").html(options);
    })




})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("form#search").changeType();
});
```

Fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fF38L/

EDIT - to make it work on IE8 take off the console.log()

http://jsfiddle.net/fF38L/1/

Comment: Nicola,Thank you for showing interest in my question really. But http://jsfiddle.net/fF38L/ running this code not work again. When I selected IT show (Programmer,Solutions Architect,Database Developer). But When I selected Programmer not show (example1,example2)

Comment: It works for me: what browser are you using?I tested it on firefox and chrome and it works

Comment: Yes it works on firefox. But I am use this code my panel. never know what browser and will enter. internet explorer, the console is undefined error

Comment: Yes i corrected that by taking off all console.log() calls and it should work in the new fiddle

Comment: Thanks Nicola it works now in ie8. Really been very helpful in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

Try `var data = eval('your json-string')`, that should work, I think.

Comment: If you listen to Douglas Crockford, `eval` is evil.  You should consider using the json2.js script and calling `var data = JSON.parse('your_json_string');` instead.  It will insulate you from potential scripting attacks or malicious "json" data.

Comment: Thanks for answers. But I could not get the result. Change second selectbox show this values in third selectbox. How can I do this?.

Comment: um.. I probably misunderstood the problem :/