# How can I populate data in Dropdown using Json and JQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, json

```
    var technicianServiceUrl = "../../../AJAX/Common/BankingServiceAjax.svc/";
    var proxyTechnician = new serviceProxy(technicianServiceUrl);
    var technicians;

    function OnGetNotes() {
        proxyNotes.invoke("SearchBranchesByBankID",
                { "request":
                    {
                        "BankID": 1
                    }
                }, OnGetNotesComplete, OnError);


    }
    function OnGetNotesComplete(result) {

        var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(result);
        technicians = obj.Branches;
    }
```

I want The OnGetNotesComplete to populata the data in my Dropdown. The return will will be array

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2205559/populating-dropdown-menu-with-json-data                                          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7213892/json-dropdown-list                                       http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8950025/i-need-help-populating-my-dropdown-with-my-json-response

Comment: the return will be array